# How to know in C# that program is running on Parallels on a Mac running XP SP2 or VmWare on a Mac running Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, parallels

I am using the following code to indicate if code is executed on virtual machine.

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem"))
{
    using (var items = searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            string manufacturer = item["Manufacturer"].ToString().ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: " + manufacturer);
            Console.WriteLine("Model: " + item["Model"].ToString());
            if ((manufacturer == "microsoft corporation" && item["Model"].ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Contains("VIRTUAL"))
                || manufacturer.Contains("vmware")
                || item["Model"].ToString() == "VirtualBox")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: " + manufacturer);
                Console.WriteLine("Model: " + item["Model"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.Read();
```

But in addition to that I have to know if it is a Parallel or VnWare. Any idea? 
Thank you

Base on the answer provided Final code will be like that, it works for me ok:

```
                using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem"))
            {
                //TODO: Have to verify the difference between Parallel and Vm
                using (var items = searcher.Get())
                {
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        string manufacturer = item["Manufacturer"].ToString().ToLower();
                        string model = item["Model"].ToString().ToLower();
                        if (manufacturer.Contains("parallels") && model.Contains("parallels"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Parallels Detected");
                        }
                        else if(manufacturer.Contains("vmware"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("VMWARE Detected");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this on VMware Fusion yields:

> Manufacturer: vmware, inc.
>   Model: VMware Virtual Platform

Based on [this](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/facter/2.4.1/files/lib/facter/virtual.rb), it looks like you would be safe checking whether Manufacturer or Model contains the string "parallels" to determine if it's running on parallels.